# Checking Global Entry Renewal Status

Tags: global-entry

I submitted my Global Entry renewal application 3 1/2 months ago. Checking the TTP Dashboard show "Wait for conditional approval" status. I've submitted inquires and get a "form letter" response saying it can take up to 120 days for approval.

How can I check the status beyond the simple "online/inquiry - form letter" response?

Just a note, my wife submitted her renewal on the same day and was approved within a week.

Comment: I contacted the CBP with a similar question and I was told I just keep watching the TTP dashboard - they won't give any extra detail.

Answer (score 3):

The CBP still has a big pile of applications from the shutdown, so the long wait might still be expected. As long as you have applied for the renewal, you can still use Global Entry for 6 months after the expiration date:

> If you submit a renewal application before your membership expires, you will be able to continue to use benefits up to 6 months after your membership expiration date, if your renewal does not get processed in time.

https://www.cbp.gov/travel/trusted-traveler-programs/global-entry/frequently-asked-questions

Comment: Wow, the shutdown was ages ago. I guess we’re getting the smaller government we wanted.  /s

Comment: The situation at the Mexican border also has intensified the situation, because CBP personnel was moved there.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments:

> I contacted the CBP with a similar question and I was told I just keep watching the TTP dashboard - they won't give any extra detail.

It could be there are some issues with your application. It is normal for them to take this long. [This](https://www.sfchronicle.com/travel/article/Worried-waiting-for-your-Global-Entry-to-renew-13908463.php) news article says to renew as early as possible as this is recently common to have such a long wait.